# json converting characters to random charaters

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

Hi i have email address in my database e.g "abc@yahoo.co.in" and when I retrieve it i am getting the same on my controller as well before returning that object to client but when i alert that value on my java script page, "@" is converting to some random characters and not giving proper display. How can i solve this.?

server code :

```
enter code here

 public AppUser findById(@FormParam("employeeId") String eId ){

      int id=Integer.parseInt(eId);
      AppUser appUser=null;
      appUser= evaluatorService.findById(id);
      return appUser;
   }
```

while debugging appUser it is giving me proper data.

my client side code :

```
 $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'rest/evaluator/fetchEvaluatorById',
    data : {

     'employeeId' : employeeId
    },
    success : function(data) {
     $('#evaluatorDetailEdit').dialog({
      width: 400,
            height: 400,
     });
     alert(data.email);


     $('#employeeId').val(data.employeeId);
     $('#name').val(data.name);
     $('#lastName').val(data.lastName);
     $('#email').val(data.email);


    }
   });
```

Comment: What kind of random character is it?

Comment: "n@yash.com" this is my actual email id in database and i am getting "n&#x40;yash.com"

Comment: It's not a "random character". It's HTML encoding for special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some hacky jquery-workaround - maybe there are better solutions, but this should work:

```js
var original = "&#x40;";
alert("Original: " + original);

// Hacky jquery-workaround: 
// 1. pasting encoded text as html in a "virtual" textarea and
// 2. get the decoded text:
var decoded = $('<textarea/>').html(original).text();
alert("Decoded: " + decoded);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, every `@` are change to `&#x40;`.
In fact, `&#x40;` is the HTML entity to represent the character `&#x40;`.

You should convert *(HTML entity decode)* the character on your server.
For example, in PHP, just call this function on your email strings: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php